# Applying Windows 8 Theme Dashboard to my Website designed in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, css, microsoft-metro

Can any one help me out to apply the windows 8 metro-ui theme to my website home page.
I have designed my website in ASP.NET but want my dashboard to look alike the metro-ui style.
However I am finding it difficult to apply those css style to my dashboard.
I want to apply the different tiles with image-slider,tile-slider etc. and some tile buttons on whose click event i can call my aspx pages.
Please can anyone help me out to achieve my task.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the following website for the template 4 metro ui styles...

[site1](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/free-windows8-metro-ui-templates.html)

[site2](http://metroui.org.ua/)

[site2](http://metro-webdesign.info/)

Comment: Thank you it helped me achieve some of the functionalists... :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is some more sites

[metro-bootstrap](http://talkslab.github.com/metro-bootstrap/index.html) based on [twitter bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/)

[Collection of 5 Best Metro Style Bootstrap Theme](http://enbeeone3.com/collection-of-5-best-metro-style-bootstrap-theme/)

[BootMetro : Metro style web framework](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/)

[10 Metro Bootstrap Templates : Metro Themes For Twitter Bootstrap](http://www.ma-no.org/en/content/index_10-metro-bootstrap-templates_1265.php)

Answer (score 1):

This particular link also helped me in achieving my goal:
http://metroui.org.ua/tiles.php